# Set 3D cursor to stay at center at all times?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, 3d-cursor

I don't use the 3D cursor much and it usually causes more problems then it's useful to me. I know <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> moves it to center, but is there a way I can keep it there (even if I accidentally press LMB?)

Comment: You can disable the hotkey, in the user preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In User Preferences you can change the assigned key that sets the location of the 3D Cursor. I would recommend setting it to `Shift` + `Left Click` so you can still move it when necessary, but you won't relocate it by accidentally left clicking anywhere.

Comment: I did this but then immediately accidentally pressed shift + left click. So I set it to shift ctrl alt right click :)